# Printing unique_ptr to cout

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Not able to understand why this is failing?

```
int *p = new int(10);
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(p);
// Below line gives compilation error.
std::cout << "Value of ptr        " << ptr << std::endl;
// Below line works well.
std::cout << "Value pointed ptr   " << *ptr << std::endl;
std::cout << "Value of ptr->get() " << ptr.get() << std::endl;
```

I understand it this way:

Say address of p is 100, address of new allocated memory is 200.

```
p                new allocated memory
----------       ---------
   200              10
----------       ---------
100              200


ptr
----------
   200
----------
300
```

In above depiction, unique_ptr is pointing to newly allocated memory itself, avoiding 'p'. So, should not printing 'ptr' give me 200?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(p);
> // Below line gives compilation error.
> std::cout << "Value of ptr        " << ptr << std::endl;
> ```

To make it possible to use the usual `<<` syntax to print an object of some class using `cout`, there must be a proper overload of `operator<<` implemented.

For example, if you have a class X, if you want to enable the `cout << x` syntax, you can overload `operator<<` like this:

```
#include <ostream> // for std::ostream

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X& x)
{
  // Implement your output logic for 'x'
  ...

  return os;
}
```

The C++ standard library designers chose not to implement such an overload for `std::unique_ptr`; this is why you get the compilation error when you try to use `<<` with instances of `unique_ptr`s.

Answer (score 8):

> So, should not printing 'ptr' give me 200?

It should, if the standard library specified `std::unique_ptr` should be streamable into standard streams. In other words, that an overload of `operator <<` for `std::unique_ptr` should exist.

However, the standard specifies no such thing, and therefore streaming a `unique_ptr` results in a compilation error (no `operator <<` accepts it). The solution is as you have found: if you need to stream the pointer, get the pointer:

```
stream << ptr.get()
```

Comment: Oho. Make sense. Buy what was stopping c++ community to overload <<?

Comment: @HemantBhargava : Not really needed.  The C++ standard is already too big (*), adding stuff that almost no-one would use would make it bigger.  *: No, I don't have a good suggestion for what to remove.

Comment: @MartinBonner As for thinning suggestions, `std::vector<bool>` comes to mind.

Comment: I don't buy the "C++ is already too big" argument. I actually recall some C++ conferences were they compared the C++ standard library to the .NET Framework, which was much bigger. There's always room to add convenient stuff to the standard library. All in all, we can simply print std::strings without calling .c_str(); to me, it makes sense to just print a unique_ptr just like for ordinary pointers, without calling .get().

Comment: @Mr.C64 I also don't agree with the standard being "too big" as the primary argument for not adding stuff. However, there's a fundamental difference with your example: streaming strings is a much more common operation than streaming smart pointers, *and* streamin a `std::string` is semantically different from streaming its `c_str()` because of the potential for contained `NUL` characters.

Comment: @Angew: I agree with you on both points. Anyway, I still think that adding streaming for `unique_ptr` just like we have for ordinary raw pointers is a simple addition that would make sense.

Comment: @Mr.C64 added in C++20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_ltlt

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that prior to C++20, there is no overloaded `operator<<` for `unique_ptr`.

But starting from C++20, there is, which can be seen from [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_ltlt):

> ```
> template< class CharT, class Traits, class Y, class D >
> std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator<<( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, const std::unique_ptr<Y, D>& p );
> ```
>
> Inserts the value of the pointer managed by `p` into the output stream `os`.
>
> Equivalent to `os << p.get()`.

This means, `std::cout << ptr;` will work in C++20(&onwards).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EsW4dsYbT)